# NgRx Data - How to hook into a addOne success Action in a typesafe way?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, angular8, angular-ngrx-data

I'm new to `@ngrx/data` and I'm going through the documentation.

Using the [guide](https://ngrx.io/guide/data) I've been able to replicate what I've previously done manually - for example using the [service](https://ngrx.io/guide/data#creating-entity-data-services) on this overview page, the following works calling REST-API and adding supplier to store.

*component.ts*

```
  onSave(supplier: Supplier) {
    this.supplierService.add(supplier);
  }
```

I know for the effect I can do the following:

```
  hello$ = createEffect(
    () =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType('[Supplier] @ngrx/data/save/add-one/success'),
        tap(console.log)
      ),
    { dispatch: false }
  );
```

BUT - is there a **type-safe** way to hook into a success API call action / entity actions in general?

**Update - clarification**

I'm using `@ngrx/data` and *so I'm not creating the actions directly myself* along with the export of types.

Upon successful addition of a supplier - which after http call results in an action with type: `'[Supplier] @ngrx/data/save/add-one/success'` - I want to perform an effect. Rather than use the string `'[Supplier] @ngrx/data/save/add-one/success'` (shown above) is there a type safe hook?

Previously (when creating the actions myself) I would export a union type and do `ofType(supplierActions.addSupplier)`

**Update - closer to an answer**

Found `ofEntityType` and `ofEntityOp` which gets me closer to my aim as these work like `ofType`:

```
  hello$ = createEffect(
    () =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofEntityType('Supplier'),
        ofEntityOp(EntityOp.SAVE_ADD_ONE_SUCCESS),
        tap(console.log)
      ),
    { dispatch: false }
  );
```

Now to just find a way of typing `'Supplier'` from the `entityMetadata`

```
const entityMetadata: EntityMetadataMap = {
  Supplier: {}
};
```

Comment: Still dont understand what you trying to do ? Do you mean that you want to have some general effect that catch all the action ?

Comment: Why do you want to use magic string like that it not best practise

Comment: @TonyNgo I *don't* want to use a string - that's the question I'm asking - please re-read the question.

Comment: And that is what trying to help you using enum in my answer

Comment: Your answer is not using `@ngrx/data`, the type strings are coming *from* `@ngrx/data`, sure I could create an enum and match the strings but that doesn't prevent a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
let array = Object.keys(entityConfig.entityMetadata);
```

it will return the name of your entities, in this case “Supplier”.
then just use the array as parameter for ofEntityType

```
hello$ = createEffect(
    () =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofEntityType(array),
        ofEntityOp(EntityOp.SAVE_ADD_ONE_SUCCESS),
        tap(console.log)
      ),
    { dispatch: false }
  );
```

Comment: be aware this will fire for the SAVE_ADD_ONE_SUCCESS for all your entity types